# How to use variables inside window.onpopstate in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue Component like below:

`Test.vue`

```
private input: string = "";
private pageNumber: number = 0;

mounted() {
    window.onpopstate = function() {
      this.input = "test";
      this.pageNumber = 1;
    }
    this.init({ page: this.page, input: this.input }); // reset search state when mounted
  }
```

But if I put `this.input = "test"` inside the `window.onpopstate` function, it's log with `Property 'input' does not exist on type 'WindowEventHandlers'.`

So how can I assign value for `this.input` inside the `window.onpopstate` function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You are using the function keyword to create a function. That means your `this` can be changed. Window events like `window.onpopstate` always set `this` to window. That means you are setting `input` and `pageNumber` on `window`. To fixy this you could use an arrow function.

```js
window.onpopstate = () => {
  this.input = "test";
  this.pageNumber = 1;
}
```